# Multiple pop up on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, svg

I am trying to use circle interaction for presenting the content. I tried this below code where in it opens up the same pop up when clicked on the any circle. How can I make each circle has an individual popup of it's own?

Here is the codepen link
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YoZGyQ

```
var DRAG_THRESOLD = 10;

var containerEl = document.querySelector( '#js-circles' );
var popin = document.querySelector( '#js-popin-0' );
var popinIngredients = document.querySelector( '#js-popin-ingred-0' );
//var addButtonEl = document.querySelector( '#add-circle' );
//var deleteButtonEl = document.querySelector( '#delete-circle' );
var changeCatRed = document.querySelector( '#js-change-category-red' );
var changeCatBlue = document.querySelector( '#js-change-category-blue' );
var changeCatYellow = document.querySelector( '#js-change-category-yellow' );
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you show me your html code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way you can do it.

Add more fields to the `createCircle()` function. For example you could add a string containing the content you want to have in the associated dialog.

```
var circles = [
  createCircle(0, 0, 'small', 'red', 'Circle 1 ?', 'js-popin-1', 'Popup text one'),
]
```

Then in the `createCircle()` function, add that new field as extra `data-` attributes on the circle.

```
function createCircle (x, y, radius, color, text, popin, popintext) {
  ...
  circleEl.setAttribute('data-title', text)
  circleEl.setAttribute('data-content', popintext)
  ...
}
```

Then in the click handler for the circles, get those data values and use them to update the popup before you open it.

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('.circle');
Array.prototype.forEach.call(elements, function(el, i){
  el.addEventListener('click', function() {
    ...
    popin.querySelector('.popin-title').textContent = el.getAttribute('data-title');
    popin.querySelector('.popin-content').textContent = el.getAttribute('data-content');
    ...
  });
});
```

For that last part we needed to update the HTML for the popup. We add some class names so that we can find the right HTML elements to update.

```
<h3 class="popin-title">Blue circle 1</h3>
...
<p class="popin-content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing...</p>
```

https://codepen.io/PaulLeBeau/pen/BgWWVv (click the green circles)

Comment: Thanks Paul. How can I add html elements as content?

Comment: Use `whatever.innerHTML = el.getAttribute('data-content')`